# Provability and computability

Tags: computability, provability

Is there an algorithm whose correctness is not provable? That is, it works but we are sure that we will never know that it’s correct. I’m basically exploring the difference between computability and provability: does the former imply the latter? What’s the relationship between the two concepts?

On the one hand I think provability is stronger, because there are facts that can be proved but never verified. And if it’s provable, then you can search for the proof in finite time. On the other hand, the existence of unprovable statements is equivalent to the existence of undecidable problems, since both concepts are regarding finiteness.

Comment: The only truths which we can know to be truths are the provable ones. While there are always truths which are not provable, we have no way of discovering them (unless we're examining a smaller system, and asking if a theorem is provable to someone inside that toy universe). So any algorithm which we know to be correct must have a corresponding proof.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor No. Gödel’s first incompleteness theorem constructs a statement that is true but not provable. So what system does that theorem reside in? This system also contains such a statement, since it’s bigger and hence sufficiently strong.

Comment: As I understand it, in the _meta_-language we know that such a sentence exists. But for us, as beings living inside some logic, we can only discuss those truths which are provable.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Which feature of Gödel’s theorem makes it a meta-theorem? I think ZFC is strong enough to prove it.

Comment: Because whatever system we are proving things about (ZFC for instance) cannot also be the meta-language. Otherwise we run into variants of the liar paradox.

Comment: https://www.iep.utm.edu/par-liar/

Comment: For the correctness of an algorithm : Rice's theorem shows that there is , for example , no algorithm to decide whether a given program calculates the square of of a number for every given integer input. A statement is provable if and only if it is true under every interpretation (in other words , absolutely true). A true statement need not be provable (Goedel).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor But Gödel’s theorem is constructive; it’s a way to assemble such an unprovable statement in the target theory. Basically it says, “Give me a system, and I can pinpoint such a statement.” I’m not talking about which system Gödel’s theorem is (my bad). OK, it’s a meta-theorem. But all sufficiently strong systems contain true but unprovable statements, so not all true statements are provable. Provability is a proper subset of truth.

Comment: Put another way, proofs are countable, but truth is uncountable. That’s why Gödel could diagonalize and make a statement assert its own unprovability.

Comment: @ZiruiWang "proofs are countable, but truth is uncountable" That's false - there are only countably many sentences in the first place (assuming we're in a countable language like arithmetic or set theory, that is).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is easy to write programs whose correctness is not provable or disprovable in, say, ZFC (or whatever other computably axiomatized theory you prefer). For instance, let's say that $P$ is a program that solves some problem. Consider the program $P'$ which does the following: on an input of size $n$ it searches for a proof of size at most $n$ that ZFC is not consistent. If it finds such a proof then it gives some garbage as its output. If it doesn't find such a proof then it just does whatever $P$ would do.

Assuming ZFC is consistent, this program will solve the problem correctly. But ZFC can't prove that because then ZFC would prove that ZFC is consistent.

For what it's worth, Adam Yedidia and Scott Aaronson have worked on finding the smallest Turing machine whose behavior is not provable in ZFC. See [here](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/busybeaver.pdf) for the paper.

Comment: +1 for the interesting construction. However I feel this question more suitable for the cs site... (or maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: @WhatsUp I think this question can be considered part of computability theory, which is often considered part of math, at least in the US. So I think it's okay for this site.

Comment: @PatrickLutz: See Zirui's comment on my answer claiming that 1 = 0. And there is even a funny supporter who is bored in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an algorithm whose correctness is not provable?

Not provable **in what system**? If you do not specify the formal system, then "provability" is a completely **meaningless** concept! In any case, given any reasonable system $S$ and any algorithm $A$ that takes an input natural number and that $S$ proves to be correct, we can trivially construct an algorithm $B$ that takes the input $n$ and first checks all proofs over $S$ of length $n$, and if it ever finds a proof over $S$ of "$0=1$" then it purposely does something incorrect, otherwise it does exactly the same as $A$. Then obviously $S$ cannot prove that $B$ is correct, otherwise $S$ would also prove $\text{Con}(S)$.

Comment: Then my question is whether ZFC is consistent. Assuming large cardinals, there exist models for ZFC. Does that imply we can’t prove 0 = 1 in ZFC forever? Because you assume Con(ZFC), which could be false and everything you say here is then rubbish. Are there other systems in which ZFC is provably inconsistent?

Comment: @ZiruiWang: Your comment is nonsensical; I did not assume ZFC, nor did I assume Con(ZFC). I clearly said that **your** term "provable" is ill-defined. Even the other answer had to say "say, ZFC (or whatever other computably axiomatized theory you prefer)." Furthermore, my answer is provable in extremely weak meta-systems, so you are just absolutely wrong when you stated that if Con(ZFC) is false then what I say here is rubbish! And it is a trivial consequence of Godel's theorem that if ZFC is consistent then ZFC+¬Con(ZFC) is also consistent but obviously proves ¬Con(ZFC).

Comment: Yes, your result is provable in weak systems, but it says if S is consistent, then S does not prove Con(S). If the hypothesis is false, that is, if S or ZFC is inconsistent, then you have nothing to say. That's why I'm so concerned with the consistency of the theory. My main inspiration comes from the Buddhist Heart Sutra, which claims that a Bodhisattva after very deep thought, discovers that forms are emptiness, in other words, 1 = 0.

Comment: If you believe 1=0, then you must believe that your inspiration is nothing. Since you are not interested in real mathematics, please do not ping me anymore.

Comment: Do you know Ramanujan, the brilliant mathematician who said that every formula is an expression of the gods? Couldn’t Buddhist doctrines be an advanced achievement of mathematics? You are right that I don’t want to discuss my personal convictions publicly. But I thought you are so highly rated, maybe you could shed some light on my confusion. I myself don’t see why forms are emptiness; I can’t meditate that deeply.

Comment: I think contradiction is the ultimate goal, of which every open problem is a special case.

Comment: If you are **honestly** interested in **real** mathematics, not made-up nonsense, first admit clearly that "forms are emptiness" could be [utter nonsense](https://friendlyatheist.patheos.com/2015/12/05/study-shows-that-people-find-fake-deepak-chopra-quotations-profound). If you cannot admit that, then **I will no longer respond**.

Comment: You are asking me to accept the opposite of Buddhism, and I have enough problems accepting the actual Buddhism already. Leave me alone, be it mathematics or Buddhism!

Comment: [This paper](http://timothychow.net/consistent.pdf) speaks for me, thank God!

Comment: I mean you say it’s consistent only because you believe in certain axioms not because you see that there is no possible way to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Let’s call the length of the shortest proof of contradiction in PA the first astronomical number!

Comment: @ZiruiWang: **For the last time**, I never claimed to know anything to be consistent, and **stop disturbing me**. You ask me to leave you alone, but you are the one that incessantly bug others and post nonsense all over.

Comment: @user21820 the mentioned website puts the cart before the horse, giving the blog author's takeaway before even mentioning any details of methodology. I don't see a link to the actual study there either. You really expect people on a math Q&A site to be convinced by this sort of thing? You want people to walk away convinced that they should leave their (buddhist or other) religion based on an 'argument' that Deepak Chopra's words bypass their critical reasoning taken from a blog post that attempts to bypass critical reasoning by cart b4 horse asking ppl to "laugh at Chopra"? On Math.SE?

Comment: Anyone that claims 0 = 1 is completely laughable.

Comment: Furthermore, the website I linked **literally links the paper**. So your comment is completely empty too. Hahahaha...